# ServiceM8 Oauth Authentication not working

Tags: authentication, oauth

I am trying to set up an integration API between ServiceM8 and another 3rd party application. I need to create a webhook which requires Platform Services Authentication using Oauth. 
I have created a developer account and a store item after which I got the APP ID and APP Secret which are required for the authenticatcation.
I initiated the authentication by redirecting the user to the url
https://www.servicem8.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[App ID]&redirect_uri=[my redirect url]&scope=manage_jobs

The user was es expected directed to the login page.
However after logging in, instead of prompting the user to accept the required permissions and redirecting to the redirect_url the user is being redirected to the ServiceM8 dashboard page.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps their Oauth redirect system might have been having some issues, as it sounds like you're doing the right steps.

If you try again now do you still get the same result? If so, maybe posting a HTTP log (with any sensitive info removed) would help.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now.